# Magento search broken, don't give results

Tags: magento-1.9, search

After a few days, the search works fine.

Now, it doesn't give any result.

I've checked the configuration on Admin(backend), and its the same as the other days(i tested other types of search but the same).

Then i checked that the products that i'm looking could be searched.

I don't know what to look more now.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding the *Catalog Search Index* in *System → Index Management*.

Comment: It's done, it's not from reindex.